# Bus bar lugs for 4/0 wire utility connection

Tags: wiring

Some contractor damaged the underground utility feed to my duplex. We have 2 units with a 100A breaker each and 2 separate meters. Right now they have 3 Aluminum conductors 2 AWG running in a plastic underground conduit. The utility needs to pull new wires (because of the contractors damage). I'm trying to convince them to run bigger wires, because I would like to have 125A to each unit. They said they would pull 1/0 Aluminum with a 2 AWG neutral, but according to the [PG&E Green Book](https://www.pge.com/pge_global/common/pdfs/services/building-and-renovation/greenbook-manual-online/063928.pdf), 1/0 is only good for 125A, and since we have two units with 100A (200A total) that seems underrated.

The conduit is 2" which should allow for 4/0 conductors, but they claim one issue is that they can't connect to my current bus-bar (see picture below), this is on the utility side of the meter. Can I just buy larger lugs and ask them to install them? Wouldn't it be their responsibility since it is on the utility side of the meter? I'm having trouble finding straight-through lugs that could work for this. I think it is 2/0 Copper on the right side.

[image: Current Utility Connection]

Comment: What is the box shown in the picture rated for?  Utilities have their own rules and they vary greatly.

Comment: I don’t know where you are but in my jurisdiction in Canada, only the meter is the purview of the utility. The meter base, the box the meter sits in, is the responsibility of the property owner. Therefore you can upgrade it if you are the property owner. Talk to an electrician / electrical contractor about upgrading it if you want to upgrade the service.

Comment: I just realized that it might be easier if I ask them to run the new wires into the panel directly. The panel has lugs rated for 300 kcmil. The only question is if they are going to complain about having another 90 degree bend to make.

Comment: Check out Polaris connectors they are insulated and can do the job , big box stores even stock them these days, I am not sure where you are but the service feeder for a residential feed in the US can be 83% of the panel size (service)See 310.15.B.7 . The lugs do not have to be hard mounted if under the NEC and Polaris style usually can handle a range of sizes and are insulated so much safer than open terminals. Make sure to get Cu/Al rated they have the goop (anti oxide jell) in them.